# How to get API Curl authorisation to work via PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, drchrono-api

I am working with **dr chrono API** and am trying to initialized the First step which is **authorisation**

The API [documentation is here](https://drchrono.com/api-docs/#section/Authorization/Initial-authorization).

Here is an Authorisation sample:

```
https://drchrono.com/o/authorize/?redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI_ENCODED&response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID_ENCODED&scope=SCOPES_ENCODED
```

Here is what I have tried:

1.) I have tried the first code below

```
<?php

echo "<a href='https://drchrono.com/o/authorize/?redirect_uri=https://example_site.com/return_page.php&response_type=code&client_id=myclient-id-goeshere&scope=BASE_SCOPE:[read|write]'>Authorize</a>";


?>
```

but when the page redirects it displays error of **Invalid_scope**. Below is the error link returned.

```
https://example_site.com/return_page.php?error=invalid_scope
```

2.) Using Curl

```
$ci = 'my-client-id-goes-here';
$ci_encode = urlencode($ci);

$uri = 'https://example_site.com/return_page.php';
$uri_encode = $uri;
$url = "https://drchrono.com/o/authorize/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
    'response_type'=>'code', 
    'client_id'=>$ci_encode,
    'redirect_uri'=>$uri_encode,
    'scope'=>'BASE_SCOPE:[read|write]',
]));
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
```

Using curl code above does even redirect me at all.

I think the major problem is the scope not properly set. How can I solve this issue?

### Update

Code section for curl:

```
$ci = 'my-client-id';
$ci_encode = urlencode($ci);
$uri = 'https://example_site.com/return_page.php';
$uri_encode = $uri;
$url = "https://drchrono.com/o/authorize/?";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
    'response_type'=>'code', 
    'client_id'=>$ci,
    'redirect_uri'=>$uri,
    'scope'=>'patients:summary:read patients:summary:write calendar:read calendar:write clinical:read clinical:write'
]));
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: the docs says the parameter "redirect_uri" must contains a URL-encoded . I think you should use php function `urlencode()` : 'redirect_uri'=>urlencode($uri_encode),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `BASE_SCOPE:[read|write]` I would use `patients:summary:read patients:summary:write calendar:read calendar:write clinical:read clinical:write`

The docs say that you can choose among user, calendar, patients, patients:summary, billing, clinical and labs and compose a scope out of these values.

Comment: thanks for contributions so far.  The link code option is now working with the scope but the curl code is not working. I have updated the scope in curl but when I run the code, on the next page it  loads, it says **CSRF Failure** if I remove the back slash and question marker parameter in the API URL and then  change the API URL to **https://drchrono.com/o/authorize** it will print 1 and will not redirect.  Please can you see **Update code section for Curl** on the posts updates. Thanks

Comment: help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359210/getting-error-with-curl-and-trellis-php-wordpress